# combining two php variables

Tags: php, variables

```
    $current_month  = date('M'); 
    for($m=1; $m<=$current_month; ++$m)
    {
        $monthNamelower=strtolower(date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1))).'';

            if ($jandata!='')
            {
              echo $jandata;
            }

        echo $data2jan;  
    }
```

can i replace the month jan with the variable $monthNamelower?
I tried something like this but not working

```
    if ('$'.$monthNamelower.'data'!='')
    {
            echo '$'.$monthNamelower.'data'; 

    }
    echo '$data2'.$monthNamelower;
```

Comment: `$monthNamelower .= 'data';  if (${$monthNamelower}) {   }`

Comment: @tilz0R, write it as answer.

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand your question, maybe it is better to edit it https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. From where pops `$jandata` out? Maybe you would better use an [array](http://php.net/arrays) to store your data without using variables of variables (and if your data are already in place [compact](http://php.net/compact) is your best friend!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

```
if (${$monthNamelower . 'data'} != '') {
    echo ${$monthNamelower . 'data'}; 
}
```

If your value stored in `$monthNamelower` is `j`, it will check for variable name `jdata` and will print it.

You can test this code directly to see effect:

```
$monthNamelower = 'j';
$jdata = 'January';
if (${$monthNamelower . 'data'} != '') {
    echo ${$monthNamelower . 'data'};  //Prints 'January'
}
```

Comment: thank you ..clear explanation but not sure why its not working in my code ..my old variable is working..i'll try to figure it out first

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making your variable name as dynamic 
Just like this

```
$monthNamelower.='data';
if ($$t!='')
    {
echo $$t; 

}
```

For Example:-

```
$t='jan';
$jandate='good';
$t.='date';
echo $$t;
```

It will produce output like

[image]

I thing it will help you.